# not able to configue repository URL in jenkins

Tags: java, svn, jenkins

I am building a maven project in my local machine. When I connected my project to SVN, the SVN URL starts with "file:///". When I am trying to use the same URL to configure repository URL in jenkins, it is showing error as " unable to access"

Comment: What if you paste that URL into your browser? Does it works? Is it a locally hosted repo? Have you tried turning off your firewall?

Comment: When I paste the URL in browser, It doesnot work. And yes, it is a locally hosted URL. I tried turning off the firewall but it dint help.

Comment: That means you have a configuration error.

Comment: What step shud I take to resolve it? I am able to sync my project in STS with the SVN repo. But when I use the SVN link in Explorer, it is not working.